# What packages do i need to install on an ubuntu desktop for it to "become a server"?

Tags: 14.04, server, package-management

Alright, so due to problems connecting to a wifi network on the ubuntu server distribution, i want to install the neccesary packages for a lamp, mail and ssh server on an ubuntu desktop 14.04 lte distribution(i am able to connect to the internet with the desktop version). 
what should i install from the command line?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install such server packages on a desktop system using the `apt-get` [tasksel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel) mode (don't forget the final `^`):

- LAMP server (Linux, Apache2, MySQL, PHP)

  `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`
- Mail server

  `sudo apt-get install mail-server^`
- OpenSSH server

  `sudo apt-get install openssh-server^`

Note that you can check which packages are going to be installed using `apt-get install --dry-run <name of the task>^` before calling the above commands.

Comment: From the link you have there:
"Note: The caret (^) was generally required at the end of the command in older versions of tasksel. It is not required in newer versions of tasksel."
I assume it won't be neccesary now?

Comment: There's a tool called `tasksel` and as stated in the doc you don't need it with it. BUT apt-get does require the final `^` otherwise the tasks won't be interpreted as such.

Comment: At least in the case of `openssh-server`, the task isn't needed, is it?

Comment: @muru you're right, `openssh-server` and `openssh-server^` will install the same packages (tested using `--dry-run`)

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest using something like [webmin / virtualmin](http://www.webmin.com/) as will guide you through the setup process and beyond. It also acts as the package manager, so it keeps everything secure and easy to maintain.